# ASP.NET Identity 2: getting all users in role -- best practice

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

It seems the examples I find so far include using `context.roles.name` which doesn't exist in Identity 2. If it did I would make a statement like such:

`Context.Users.Where(u => u.roles.Any(r => r.name == "Administrator")).ToList();`

However Roles only has RoleId and UserId for properties. So to get the RoleId I use two statements like such:

```
var adminRole = db.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == "Administrator").FirstOrDefault();
string adminRoleId = (adminRole != null) ? adminRole.Id : "";
var students = db.Users.Where(u => u.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == adminRoleId)).ToList();
```

And this successfully gives me a list of users in that role. **Is this the best practice?**

The other way I have seen using the UserManager is like such:

```
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
List<ApplicationUser> administrators = new List<ApplicationUser>();
foreach (var user in context.Users.ToList())
        {
            if (userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Administrator"))
            {
                Students.Add(user);
            }
        }
```

But it seems like I would only want to use the UserManager if I was performing CRUD operations on users.

Comment: did you find an answer to this? I'm going through the same thing right now. 

I am currently doing what you did in your first example but it isn't finding the role :/ It loads all of the roles from the same context into a dropdown so I know they're there. This Identity stuff is unnecessarily difficult, or I'm just really missing something.

Comment: Yeah, so basically the first code segment doesn't work in Identity 2, but the second code segment should give you a list of users in that role. So each line in the second code segment does this:

1. Gets the role entity with the name Administrator
2. Checks if it's null, and if not, assigns roleId to a string
3. Gets a list of users where the roleId matches

It is fairly difficult, but I assume that's to accommodate different situations and requirements.